# Unable to give more than 1GB of heap memory in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

i am using windows 7 64 bit OS,8 GB of ram with java 1.8 64 bit.I added the following arguments to eclipse under VM arguments:

"**-Xms512M -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=512M**" .
But while starting tomcat it is saying "**Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap**".But with 1GB it is starting fine,as my project is big i need minimum 2GB.
Can anyone give me the solution???

Comment: Do you have 2GB of free RAM?

Comment: 32bit Windows processes can only get up to 2GB RAM (on some systems up to 3GB). Therefore you are using most likely a 32bit JVM of a 32bit JRE.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 64bit Eclipse. Otherwise you can't give your Eclipse more than 1GB of RAM.

Comment: The more important part is the JRE/JDK which is required as 64bit version. The Eclipse version should not make a difference.

Comment: i have checked under installed Jre in Eclipse. it is 64 bit,still it is not taking more than 1 GB also 4GB free RAM is available.

Comment: Is also your eclipse 64 bit?

Comment: Yes eclipse also 64 bit.